# Having both JPA and Liquibase: what to do with their configuration files?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, liquibase

My project started with JPA only and it doesn't have Spring. Later, I added Liquibase and I had some issues with the persistence unit name since it is necessary to have one to be able to use `EntityManager`.

```java
entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPU");
```

So, to be able to continue with the tables creation with Liquibase and persisting into the database with JPA, I kept both `persistence.xml` and `liquibase.properties` files, despite contaning the same database configuration.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
             version="2.2">
    <persistence-unit name="MyPU">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/jpa_specialist?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

```yaml
changeLogFile=src/main/resources/META-INF/database/dbchangelog.xml
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/jpa_specialist?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
username=root
password=root
```

I've taken a look at `liquibase-hibernate` and I didn't understand it very well but it seems to be used to generate the diff files, which is not my need at the moment.

Are both files necessary? Is there something I can do to have only one of them?

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase doesn't have a direct way to read the url/username/password information from the presistence.xml file. The liquibase-hibernate extension does add support for diff'ing a database with your java file mapping files, but doesn't change how Liquibase gets the url/username/password.

You said you were not using Spring, but if you are still in a web application, you can use the [Liquibase servlet listener](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/community-supported/servlet-listener.html) to run Liquibase which pulls the connection from a pre-configured datasource. JPA can pull from that same pre-configured datasource instead of re-defining the configuration as well.

Otherwise, unless you want to do a bit of custom Java coding to parse the persistence.xml file and pass it into Liquibase, you do need both files.

To avoid the repetition you could do something like defining build properties in your maven/gradle/whatever setup and have `<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="${database.url}"/>`in your persistence.xml source file, and `url: ${database.url}` in your liquibase.properties file.